# How can I add my name, as well as page number, to the right header of the document?

Tags: header-footer, numbering, page-numbering, page

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\textheight=10in
\pagestyle{empty}
%\raggedbottom
\raggedright

%  \renewcommand{\encodingdefault}{cg}
  %\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{lgrcmr}

\def\bull{\vrule height 0.8ex width .7ex depth -.1ex }
% DEFINITIONS FOR RESUME
\newcommand{\area}[2]{\vspace*{-9pt} \begin{verse}\textbf{#1}   #2 \end{verse}  }
\newcommand{\lineunder}{\vspace*{-8pt} \\ \hspace*{-18pt} \hrulefill \\}
\newcommand{\header}[1]{{\hspace*{-15pt}\vspace*{6pt} \textsc{#1}} \vspace*{-6pt} \lineunder}
\newcommand{\employer}[3]{{ \textbf{#1} \hfill{#2}\\ {\textbf{\emph{#3}}}\\  }}
\newcommand{\contact}[3]{
\vspace*{-8pt}
\begin{center}
{\LARGE \scshape {#1}}\\
#2 \\
#3 
\end{center}
\vspace*{-8pt}
}
\newenvironment{achievements}{\begin{list}{$\bullet$}{\topsep 0pt \itemsep -2pt}}{\vspace*{4pt}\end{list}}
\newcommand{\schoolwithcourses}[5]{
 \textbf{#1} #2 \hfill{#3} \\ #4\\ #5 \\
\vspace*{5pt}
}
\newcommand{\school}[4]{
 \textbf{#1} #2 $\bullet$ #3\\ 
#4 \\
}
% END RESUME DEFINITIONS
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Well, begin with not using the `empty` pagestyle. You can define your own headers and footers with a dedicated package, such as `fancyhdr` or `titleps`, which comes with `titlesec`.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello and welcome to stackexchange! Your preambel looks a bit chaotic and the provided MWE doesn't work. Furthermore, better use the `scrlayer-scrpage`-package instead of the sometimes problematic `titlesec`-package for customizing the header or footer.

---

**You could create it like that:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\ihead{Your name}
\ohead{And the pagenumber \thepage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}

    \section{Introduction}

        Test.

\end{document}
```

---

**The result looks like that:**

[image]

---

Please write some short description of your request in future. It is difficult to understand what exactly you want to do. Furthermore, please mark your question as "answered" by clicking on the hook when you got a solution.